# How do I convert size_t to String^?

Tags: string, stdstring, size-t

I saw the thread for converting size_t to std::string but I want to convert to the system string.  I suppose I could convert to string and convert that to String^ but I'd rather find a direct method.  Does anyone know how to do this with as little code as possible?

Comment: Should be possible to cast it to a `UInt32` and call `ToString` ?

Comment: Add the language tag. `std::string` looks like C++, what is `String`?

Comment: String^ as in system string.  I'm using visual studio and they have to be different for some reason.  String^s are the bane of my existence.

Comment: I'll look up ToString.  Thanks :)